# My discord bot isnt responding to commands

Tags: node.js

I have a Discord Bot, it turns on, but it doesn't answer to commands.
Here's my code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client( {intents: 32767}, );
 { 
   partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION', 'USER', 'GUILD_MEMBER']
 }

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Estoy ON')
  client.user.setActivity('Ark Survival Evolved', { type: "PLAYING"});
});

client.once('message', (message) => {
  if(message.content.startsWith('ping')) {
    message.channel.send(`pong !!`);
  }

});

client.login('MY TOKEN');
```

I need help. I tried to do everything, but it doesn't work.
I'm in the latest version of node.js and in the latest version in discord.js
I have tried in 5 versions, but I can't do anything.

I tried to use a prefix, without prefix... But it dont works.
I have tried 3 codes and nothing.

Comment: can you post your error messages? or have you debugged your code?

Comment: do you have discord? i can show you what happends. I debugged it, and it dont have any error.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite obviously because you're using the magical "all" intents code. Consider replacing it with the proper intents instead of using `32767`. The use above is also correct as the `message` event is deprecated and no longer logs any errors.

And as for whatever reason the partials is completely out of the `Discord.Client` options, I do not know.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
  ],
  partials: [
    Discord.Partials.User,
    Discord.Partials.Message
    Discord.Partials.Channel
    Discord.Partials.Reaction
    Discord.Partials.GuildMember
   ]
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Estoy ON');
  client.user.setActivity('Ark Survival Evolved', { type: "PLAYING"});
});

client.once('messageCreate', (message) => {
  if(message.content.startsWith('ping')) {
    message.channel.send(`pong !!`);
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

I've changed `message` to `messageCreate` and rearranged the intents and partials into the new discord.js@v14 versions and changed the "magical intents" to a proper intent array.

Also please ensure that you have the message privileged intents enabled in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers)

Comment: I've tried that with 3 bots, but it dont sends messages what i'm doing bad :(

Comment: @Alxxpm have you tried enabling message intents?

Comment: Yes I did but it dont works i dont know what i have to do

Comment: @Alxxpm Are there any errors at all? If not, could you please ensure that your bot has the correct permissions? Is really unusual that your bot is having issues and the community aren't able to replicate the issue.

Comment: There aren't any errors, i did 3 roles al discord with administrator for them

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  if(message.content.startsWith('ping')) {
    message.channel.send(`pong !!`);
  }
});
```

Comment: It doesnt works, and I tried to use a old code what i have used but bot dont asnwers to me

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Did you try to put a console.log into the event to see if it fires? Are you sure you need partials? Are the intents correct (I wouldn't use an intent integer it makes it less readable)? Is the token correct? Did you start the node app?

Comment: I dont have any error message, i tried to put a console and i dont have any problem, the token its correct and i have started on Visual Studio Code the node app, i've put partials because a user telled me i have to put they there

Comment: Paritals are generaly not recommended if you don't exactly know what you're doing